# In some books on functional programming instance methods delegate to binary functions defined in companion object. Any practical reason behind it?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I often see this:

```
class A { def operation(b: B) = A.operation(a,b) }
object A { def operation(a: A, b: B) = /* impl */ }
```

Instead of just:

```
class A { def operation(b: B) = /* impl */ }
object A { def operation(a: A, b: B) = a.operation(b) }
```

Or even just:

```
class A { def operation(b: B) = /* impl */ }
```

Mainly in books on functional programming, but I've also seen this kind of pattern in our production code a few times. Meanwhile `operation` in almost **never** called as `A.operation(a,b)` - instead it's always `a.operation(b)` or `a operation b`, which makes sense since infix notation is just (perhaps arguably) more readable.

Why define method in a companion object in the first place if you never use it? Why would you want to delegate to it? Is there **any** practical reason for this or is it simply some kind of "everyones doing it since X, so we might as well do?"

Comment: I don't know of any Scala implementation, or even any implementation of *any* class-based OO language, that duplicates methods in every object instead of keeping them in the class. That's pretty much the whole reason for the existence of classes in the first place, after all.

Comment: Probably `A.operation` is even private. The idea probably is to juts build pure functions and provide the method like syntax. In any case, there isn't really any reason for prefer one over the another, other than style. PS: GADTs there is sometimes a gatch with pattern matching where it only works if it is done outside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo, the main reason is that `def operation(a: A, b: B) = ???` can and should be implemented as a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) and this semantic indicates this more clearly comparing to `class A { def operation(b: B)}`.

The last one is an object-oriented approach. And, if one is familiar with OOP, it may change the state of `A` thus having a side effect.

So, it's all to indicate that implementation is side effect free.